# Firebase onAuthStateChanged keeps refreshing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase in JavaScript.

I use the onAuthStateChanged function to check if the user is logged in, and then redirect to the appropriate html page.

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
        // Logged in
        console.log("logged in!");
        window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
        fetchFromDB();
    } else {
        console.log("Logged out!");
        //window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
});
```

However, it keeps refreshing the page constantly like it's in some infinite loop. I'm not sure what to do here.

Help will be appreciated a lot :)

Comment: Redirecting causes a page refresh, which signs the user back in, which triggers onAuthStateChanged...which causes a redirect...n

Answer (score 4):

When the page loads, Firebase **starts** restoring the signed in user from the local storage of your browser. This requires a call to the server (a.o. to see if the account has been deleted/disabled), which takes some time.

So initially your `onAuthStateChanged` gets called with `null` as there is no current user. Then when the authentication state is restored the listener gets called again with the user profile.

My guess it that you're taking some action in the initial `null` (like redirecting to `index.html`), and that target page then redirect back to `dashboard.html` when it gets the user profile.

---

It's easiest to work with Firebase in a single-page application, as you'd have only a single page load in that case. But if you have multiple pages, you'll need to write code that waits for the authentication state to settle.

Some common ways that I know of:

1. Ignore the initial `null` that your `onAuthStateChanged` callback gets. But keep in mind that the user state *may* not be restorable in which case the `null` is all you get, so you may need to act on that after a while.
2. Design your flow so that you end up in the right spot. This may only work in a single-page application, but I use this one most often: when the page loads (and the user is `null`), I show a log-in screen. Then when the user profile is restored I navigate to the dashboard. This means that users may briefly see the login screen, but I don't find this too distracting. If you do, read on...
3. You *can* store a value in local storage yourself when the user is signed in. Then on a page reload, you can check that value and if it exists: assume that the restore of their auth state will succeed, and show the dashboard first. If the sign-in fails, you can then redirect back to the login screen after a timeout. So this inverts the path of #2, and requires quite some work, but removes the temporary login screen for your returning users.

Comment: BTW: this pattern of a property having a `null` value initially and then, at a later time...possibly milliseconds later, having a value is pretty common in React-based applications.  This isn't about Firebase Auth as much as it is simply React.  You want to write your components to handle the "initial loading" situation.

Answer (score 0):

here, If you are working with `react` this might work.

```
useEffect(() => {
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
  setUser(currentUser);
  console.log("user Changed");
})}, [])
```

`onAuthStateChanged` runs everytime component is re-render so `useEffect` will help in this case.